# Convert part of an string arrays to integer arrays

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am scanning a text file for details in the form of

Jackson,English,4,5,6,3

Quill,Maths,4,5,6,3

to create a array-list of student and score.of so Name, course, marks.

```
String parts [] = line.split(",")   //create string parts arrays, with each element seperated by , 
String name = parts[0];
String course = parts[1];
```

but i dont know how to create the marks into integer arrays  so i can use it into a constructor of student arraylist.

```
Student s = new Student(name,course, int[] marks)
```

any help?

Comment: You can stream the part of the array and map them to an int

Comment: An easy solution is to parse the `parts[2]` up to `parts[5]` via [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) while adding them to a new `int[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "Jackson,English,4,5,6,3";
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    String name = parts[0];
    String course = parts[1];
    int[] marks = Arrays.stream(parts)
        .skip(2)
        .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
        .toArray();
    Student student = new Student(name, course, marks);
}
```

Comment: or `int[] marks = IntStream.range(2, parts.length).map(i -> Integer.parseInt(parts[i])).toArray();`

Comment: thanks, i thought it need to be Student(name, course, Int [] marks).

Student student = new Student(name, course, marks); works too i guess